# Chrome extension with Angular - make a REST API Call

Tags: angular, rest, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As I am trying to build a Chrome extension with Angular 10, I need to make a REST API call.
It seems that HttpClient won't work and that I need to use a "background script" to make such a thing.

Is that right? And how could I manage to make it work? :)
Calling the API in the background script, storing it in local storage and reading it from my extension? I think that's too tricky.

Here's how I've tried to do it:

```
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public fetchCoins(): Observable<CoinDto[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CoinDto[]>(environment.coingecko_api + 'coins/list');
  }
```

Comment: have you found a solution in this one?

Comment: Well.. it somehow started to work. I don't remember changing anything in particular, I just tried again later. 
If you're facing the same issue, maybe compare your project with [mine](https://github.com/bo0st3r/Ronin_Extension)